# What should I do to solve this?

Tags: android, android-studio

I just installed Android studio.
When I select new project, I'm not getting the complete dialog box (as in the next,finish buttons are not seen).

What should I do to get the complete dialog box?

Comment: Which version of Android Studio you have downloaded.

Download android studio properly from below link

https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html

Answer (score 0):

you probably didn't install something such as jdk or sdk u need

Comment: if you are not installed `jdk` it's impossible to install Android Studio.

Comment: will it let you continue without any any api's from the sdk manager?

Answer (score 0):

Just be sure that you have the Android SDK as well, Because is possible download only the IDE. If you have everything, try to reinstall in another folder

Answer (score 0):

I think this issue may be occurring in your case due to window alignment of android studio(as I was facing). So you're not getting complete dialog box (next, finish button).

Because these buttons hide behind of Window Taskbar. So short solution is auto hide your window taskbar.

Right Click on taskbar-->Properties-->Taskbar-->click on check box (Auto-hide the taskbar)

then apply and ok.

Hope this will help you.